# cap deploy - Using scp instead of sftp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

My cap deploy script has

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

by default.

When I run `cap deploy` command, it's always throwing an error saying

```
upload via sftp failed... : Resource temporarily unavailable (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

How to use scp instead of sftp to check if it works?